# Pip uninstall issue in single stage docker

Tags: python, docker, pip

I am using single stage docker to build my Python API image and now due to security vulnerabilities for PIP,I will have to uninstall it from docker file but while doing that getting this error.

```
2024-02-19T07:11:11.3780709Z PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/bin/pip' -> '/tmp/pip-uninstall-4wwhhueu/pip'
```

Could you please help me with the exact way to uninstall Pip from the docker file?

I have tried below uninstall commands mentioned in my docker file.

```
FROM artifactory.sdlc.ctl.gcp.db.com/dkr-public-local/gcp-community-images/python:3.10
`<kbd># expect a build-time variable<kbd>
ARG ENV_VAR
# use the value to set the ENV var default
ENV APP_ENV=$ENV_VAR
# Set working directory to /app
WORKDIR /app</kbd>
ENV http_proxy=http://sp-surf-proxy.intranet.db.com:8080
ENV https_proxy=http://sp-surf-proxy.intranet.db.com:8080
ENV no_proxy=.googleapis.com,metadata.google.internal,status.cloud.google.com, 
COPY requirements.txt /app
RUN pip install -r /app/requirements.txt \
    --user \
    --disable-pip-version-check \
    --no-cache-dir
# binaries and plugin

# uninstall pip
RUN python3 -m pip uninstall pip -y
RUN rm -rf /usr/bin/pip*

COPY . /app
RUN ls /app
RUN python3 --version
CMD ["python3", "/app/src/app.py"]
```

`

My ultimate goal is to remove pip completely so there is no reference exist of it in the image.

Comment: From `/home/nonroot/` I guess you have a command `USER nonroot` somewhere in the Dockerfile but you didn't show it to us. Anyway this command makes `pip unstall` to fail. Use `USER root` or `sudo pip uninstall`

Answer (score 0):

### TL;DR Solution

Add the following to your Dockerfile to switch temporarily to a root user to allow the uninstall.

```
USER root

# uninstall pip
RUN python3 -m pip uninstall pip -y

USER nonroot

RUN rm -rf /home/nonroot/.local/bin/pip*
```

### Explanation

The problem comes from your base image, since this works just fine in an official python image:

```
FROM python:3.10

RUN python3 -m pip uninstall pip -y
```

I assume based on the context that the (company local?) base image has a non-root user set up by default, because I can reproduce the error by doing this:

```
FROM python:3.10

RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash nonroot

USER nonroot

RUN python3 -m pip uninstall pip -y
```

Comment: Thanks..I have updated my error and pip path,could you please have a look at it again.

Comment: Sorry did you update something? I see the same file and error in the questions as originally.